# List of Anti-Cheat Packages for MMOs?

Tags: mmo, anti-cheat

i would like to start this topic for programs to counter-attack [link text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheating_in_online_games).

I am not aware of a big list but with everyone's help i hope to make this a fine topic.

Posting format:

**NAME:** nProtect GameGuard

**GAME TYPE:** any type of game

**Website:** http://global.nprotect.com/product/gg.php

**FEATURES?**

- Protect the users' PC from fast
  evolving hacking technologies and
  viruses.
- Real-time protection, diagnose
  various patterns latest hacking tools
  that can harm games, but also memory
  debugging prevention technology will
  be applied, completely blocking
  hacking tools through real-time
  hacking tool monitoring and blocking
  function.
- Blocks hacking attacks through memory
  scan
- Blocks online outflow of personal
  information

Comment: Duplicate with http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/anti-cheat-for-mmos-issues-and-solutions?

Comment: That question is asking for known issues and their solutions, not specific software to help with it. I don't think it's a duplicate. Plus, it's community wiki so I think it's OK.

Comment: @Prix you should move your two answers into two actual answers to the question so people can vote on them.

Comment: @Sean will do thanks. @coderanger it is not a duplicate, and both are community wiki this one is specific related to what softwares we have on the market, how to contact them and which features they have, the other one is about what you do as counter messures, if you just rely on a tool like these or make your own code and so forth...

Comment: Having read both, I'll admit they're *marginally* not duplicates - but I'd *really* like to see a **title change** for one of them. Maybe change this question to "List of Anti-Cheat *Packages* for MMOs". The word *solution* in both is misleading (and annoying, in that software companies have decided to over-use the word *solution* for what is just *software*).

Comment: @Cyclops thanks i will do that now, my english is not very good i may lack of some words in my sentences so i ended up like this eheh ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NAME:** xTrap

**GAME TYPE:** any type of game

**WEBSITE:** http://www.wiselogic.co.kr/product4.htm

**FEATURES?**

Unfortunately I can't read korean and I havent found much information regarding this one but I've seen quiet an amount of games using it.

Answer (score 10):

**Name:** Writing secure networking code.

**Game Type:** Any, but especially good for MMOs.

**Website:** Any real trusted networking standard, [Writing Secure Code](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735617228), and many others specific to your language.

**Features:**

- Fewer angry or confused users.
- No unexpected overhead due to poorly-written third party programs.
- Likely to have trickle-down effects improving the rest of your project's code.
- Cannot be defeated by kernel drivers, virtual machine trickery, or [other well-documented undetectable methods of cheating](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132271915).

Comment: I'd be curious if the person voting me down actually thinks this is unreasonable, or is just voting me down because it's not a "real answer" (even though my previous employer shipped 3.5 MMOs without anti-cheat packages, had our data formats cracked wide open, and to my knowledge never had anyone gain a measurable advantage by hacking the client).

Answer (score 1):

**NAME:** PunkBuster

**GAME TYPE:** FPS

**WEBSITE:** http://www.evenbalance.com/

**FEATURES?**

- Real-time scanning of memory by PB
  Client on players' computers
  searching for known hacks/cheats
- Throttled two-tiered background
  auto-update system using multiple
  Internet Master Servers to provide
  end-user security ensuring that no
  false or corrupted updates can be
  installed on players' computers
- Frequent status reports (highly
  encrypted) are sent to the PB Server
  by all players and the PB Server
  raises a violation when necessary
  which causes the offending player to
  be removed from the game and all
  other players are informed of the
  violation
- PB Admins can also manually remove
  players from the game for a specified
  number of minutes or permanently ban
  if desired
- PB Servers can optionally be
  configured to randomly check player
  settings looking for known exploits
  of the game engine
- More ...

Answer (score 1):

**NAME:** sXe Injected

**GAME TYPE:** FPS

**WEBSITE:** http://www.sxe-anticheat.com/introduccion

**FEATURES?**

- Anti-Wallhack
- LocalBan
- 16bpp Detection
- Screenshot
- Anti-Speedhack

Answer (score 1):

NAME: X-Ray Anti-Cheat

GAME TYPE: multiplayer Steam games (Counter Strike, Team Fortress 2, ... )

Website: http://www.xraygaming.com/

FEATURES?

- X-ray uses state-of-the-art methods to protect you and your online gaming experience.
- It will periodically take screenshots of what you are seeing in-game
- It wwill scan for known cheats and bad processes in the background to help with cheat detection.
- When you are finished playing your game, X-ray will upload these screenshots to our servers, where our experienced admin team and massive userbase will help catch cheaters by reviewing screenshots and 'flagging' them if they appear suspicious.

Comment: thx for the contribution ... it was getting hard to find others

Answer (score 1):

**NAME:** FAIRPLAY by Use It Better

**GAME TYPE:** flash games

**WEBSITE:** http://www.useitbetter.com/fairplay

**FEATURES?**

recording gameplays to detect

- speedhacks
- non-human behaviors (bots and trainers)
- exploits
- memory and code attacks

Answer (score 0):

**NAME:** HackShield

**GAME TYPE:** any type of game

**WEBSITE:** http://www.hackshields.com/

**FEATURES?**

- Memory Hacking Protection
- Speed Hack Protection
- Debugger Protection
- Auto Update