# Export object or scene with textures

Tags: 3d, textures, 3dsmax, asset-workflow

Is there a way to export or publish some work to a folder so somebody else can open the .max file and does not have to reassign all the textures again?

My problem is that i used lots of textures straight from my texture folder in a completely different folder tree. So when i sent the file to someone else he needs to rebuild this tree exactly the same as i did or reassign every texture.

If there is no option like that do i have to change my workflow, in case others need to work with my files, and keep everything in the same folder? What is normal procedure to keep everything organized and compatible for each user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 3DSMax doesn't actually use the textures themselves (it just imports them into a format it can use), it's not likely going to be able to export them along with the project file. Exporting is typically done when changing formats, not as a method of "putting everything in one place".

This problem is usually handled with [source control](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/51649/source-control-for-storing-everything-of-game-project). Not only does this easily re-create the directory structure of your project, it also ensures you have backups of textures and models should something go wrong. Pick a [source control tool](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/480/version-control-for-game-development-issues-and-solutions) you like and check in your project. Then, when you want to share with someone, they just need to check out your project and it'll be in the same structure as it was the last time you checked it in.

To make this a bit more foolproof, you'll want to make sure that [3DsMax is using relative paths for its resources](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/13/ENU/Autodesk%203ds%20Max%202011%20Help/index.html?url=./files/WSf742dab041063133-5029f504112a1ce7dbd-7fe9.htm,topicNumber=d0e467280), instead of absolute paths.