# Cry Engine 3 vs UDK

Tags: unity, udk

Me and a bunch of guys from my University are thinking about getting started in game development, but, even though the game design is kind of ready, we are stucked at the point "which Engine should we choose".

At first, we were thinking about Unity3D Free, in particular because we are pretty familiar with C# and, even better, it's completely free, but on the other hand there are some cons like no dynamic shadowing that make the realization of our game kinda hard.

So, we are thinking about moving either to UDK or Cry Engine, since they are not as expensive as Unity3D Pro (at least before the game deployment) .

The thing we are worried the most, though, is that we are kind of scared about the support for team work(i mean, that we might find it hard to coordinate our efforts without software support), since in Unity3D the team features are part of purchasable content, and we are not interested in paying that much for a project we are not even sure we can complete.

So, finally, I hope one of you knows the mentioned engines enough to give us a tip telling which one offers better team features and is advisable for guys that have barely worked before on videogames but have good object oriented programming skills.

Our game is an exploration game.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what team features unity offers, but this may be a related question. [Version control for game dev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/480/version-control-for-game-development-issues-and-solutions)

Comment: This question is much too vague to be answered.  You have a lot of "maybes", "worries", "thinking"s, and such.  It would be difficult for someone to provide a real answer.  Honestly, as a student myself, I find just trying stuff out is the best way to eliminate those problems.  I would do some more research on the existing tools and try some stuff out.  Nothing is stopping you from experimenting.  If you have a specific question about those technologies as you try them, you will be more than welcome to ask those questions here.

Comment: You can read the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) to get a sense of the kinds of questions that are appropriate for Gamedev.

Answer (score 1):

While the feature is poorly documented, UDK has the option to integrate with Subversion, so your team can keep assets synchronised.

See this tutorial for more information: http://www.stubbornhorse.com/?p=135

Cry Engine SDK is lacking this, or any equivalent feature, as far as I can tell.

Furthermore, from having played with the two (several years with UDK, a few months with Cry), the documentation for both is less than stellar, but Cry Engine's is absolutely woeful.

If you're on any kind of time restraint, UDK get my thorough recommendation as the easier of the two to learn.

Comment: I would still be cautious about UDK, as I'm pretty sure it still only supports the 15-year-old and fairly obscure Unreal script.

Comment: Unreal Script and Kismet (node-based visual scripting). However, Unrealscript is surprisingly powerful language, and quite easy to learn.

Answer (score 1):

From a team-support standpoint: Definitely UDK, since it integrates with Perforce (if that's really that important to you)

As far as eyecandy goes: CryEngine 3. No questions asked. It allows for vast, lush terrains based on marching cubes and therefore not only looks really nice but is probably the best tool for outdoor levels.

From a purely technological standpoint: id tech 4 (CDK). It comes with full source access, so it's easy to modify (if you have a talented programmer well versed in C++, that is) and the CDK (more commonly known as the Dreaded Engine) even comes with a ptex based virtual texturing approach as well as Autodesk Beast (a pretty awesome lightmapping tool)

Disclaimer: Unity3D and UDK are, by far, the easiest and most thoroughly documented of the bunch. What they lack in flexibility they make up for in efficiency. With Unity3D you can easily develop a prototype in just a few days.

Answer (score -1):

Make a big list of pros and cons of every engine.
Rate the pros and cons.
pick the one with the most score.

"no dynamic shadowing that make the realization of our game kinda hard."
- This is probably something that you can implement yourself, cant see no engine get public without having an solution to this.